# Autocad format viewer on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, 3d, autocad

I would like to be able to render autocad DWF and/or DWG files in a UIView within iOS.

Autodesk has a mac-based library, but it does not have iOS support.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoDesk provides the DWF Toolkit, written in C++. You can use C++ code in iOS apps.

http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?id=823771&siteID=123112

Comment: There is only show website. Can you please write here description of user in iPhone? i did't find c++ library in above link.