# How to view .dwg (AutoCAD) files in webview in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Want to View `.dwg` files in `UIWebView` in Iphone,
I have tried to load the URL of .`dwg` file in `webview`.But its not loading.
Please suggest any 3rd party browser or any other way to viewing .`dwg` files.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866622/autocad-format-viewer-on-ios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is the list of supported document formats, it's no AutoCAD there
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1630/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008749

you can try to use Autodesk DWF Toolkit for this
http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?id=823771&siteID=123112

Comment: what king of suggestion?

Comment: Any sample ios application  or code for opening .dwg file in webview, if any.

Comment: you can't open dwg in webview, as I mentioned  earlier. Try to investigate the toolkit from Autodesk